# How to mock a function, in a function map/dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking

I am trying to patch the `fun_1` function from the `worker_functions` dictionary and I seem to be struggling:

cli.py:

```
import sys

from worker_functions import (
    fun_1,
    fun_2,
    fun_3,
)

FUNCTION_MAP = {
    'run_1': fun_1,
    'run_2': fun_2,
    'run_3': fun_3,
}

def main():
    command = sys.argv[1]
    tag = sys.argv[2]
    action = FUNCTION_MAP[command]

    action(tag)
```

I've tried mocking `cli.fun_1` and `cli.main.action` and `cli.action` but this is leading to failure.

test_cli.py:

```
from mock import patch

from cli import main


def make_test_args(tup):
    sample_args = ['cli.py']
    sample_args.extend(tup)
    return sample_args


def test_fun_1_command():
    test_args = make_test_args(['run_1', 'fake_tag'])
    with patch('sys.argv', test_args),\
         patch('cli.fun_1') as mock_action:
        main()

        mock_action.assert_called_once()
```

Do I seem to be missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to patch the references in the `FUNCTION_MAP` dictionary itself. Use the [`patch.dict()` callable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch-dict) to do so:

```
from unittest.mock import patch, MagicMock

mock_action = MagicMock()
with patch('sys.argv', test_args),\
     patch.dict('cli.FUNCTION_MAP', {'run_1': mock_action}):
    # ...
```

That's because the `FUNCTION_MAP` dictionary is the location that the function reference is looked up.

Comment: This looks potentially brilliant.

Comment: do I import `MagicMock` from mock?

Comment: Yes, I added the import.

Comment: Flip... Now I know what separates the Padawan from those on the Council...